# How to gain access to an attribute without returning an instance or copy of the data using in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a multithread program, and I need to gain access to a Map, but I don't know how to ensure that multiple threads aren't modifying the Map. I am wondering if there is a way to create a method that is synchronized, and returns the Map within the class that when the program makes changes to it, it's reflected among the primary attribute.

Below is the code that gives me a ConcurrentModificationException. Is this because two threads are
accessing the Map at the same time? The error is occurring in the remove method. I also included the notify method because that method is being called every couple minutes and I'm wondering if this error has something to do with that method being called.

***My notifyObserver method still has some logic missing, hence the changed attribute always being true.

```
private static final Map<WeatherDotComLocation, List<Observer>> locationAndObserver = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void remove(Observer o) {
    killThread(o);
    Set<WeatherDotComLocation> weatherLocations = locationAndObserver.keySet();
    for(WeatherDotComLocation location : weatherLocations) {
        List<Observer> observerListToCheck = locationAndObserver.get(location);
        for(Observer suspectObserver : observerListToCheck) {
            if(suspectObserver.equals(o)) {
                observerListToCheck.remove(o);
            }
        }
        if(observerListToCheck.size() == 0) {
            locationAndObserver.remove(location);
        }
    }
}

public void notifyObservers() {
    Set<WeatherDotComLocation> keySet = locationAndObserver.keySet();
    for (WeatherDotComLocation location : keySet) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            WeatherManager weatherManager = new WeatherManager();
            boolean changed = true;
            if(changed) {
                List<WeatherDotComForecast> weatherForecast = weatherManager.pullData(location, 5);
                for(Observer observer : locationAndObserver.get(location)) {
                    observer.update(weatherForecast);
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "reflected among th eprimary attribute"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` only protects the block inside the synchronised.  If you return a collection to an unprotected region, this Map can be altered while being read/written outside the block.

I suspect the simplest option is to use a thread safe collection such as

```
private final Map<String, MyType> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

or

```
private final Map<String, MyType> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

These can be used in a thread safe manner without the need to use `synchronized`

Comment: Or the OP could write wrapper methods (`myGet()`, `myPut()`) for the Map which are *synchronized* then use the *wrapper* methods for `get()` and `put()`operations?. Then he / she will have to take care so as to avoid direct calls to `map.get()` or `map.put()`. right?. Using 'synchronizedMap()' also involves making sure we don't use the *original* map reference right?

Comment: @TheLostMind correct.  You could write your own wrapper which does the same thing as the wrapper provided by the JDK.  Having a custom wrapper is more useful if you have an operation which it doesn't already provide like `incrementCounterFor(String key)`

Comment: Agreed. The problem with `ConcurrentHashMap` is the updated data isn't guaranteed to be seen. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind anything you put into the map will be seen.  if you get an object out and play with, this might not be seen.

Comment: @PeterLawrey do I have to use final? I could use public volatile static right? Then, since ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe I would be good to go?

Comment: @MiguelJ. if you are using anything other than `final` in a thread safe context chances are you are doing something wrong.  I suggest avoiding making collections you write to `static`, and make the `final` as it is highly likely that making them `volatile` indicates a design flaw as it don't do what most people think it does.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So even though I declare the attribute as final I can still modify the Map? I thought you can't modify attributes declared as final... Is that what I'm getting confused about? To give you a little bit of background... I have a program that every ten seconds loops through and updates a list of values using the observer pattern. Then if I want, any of the observers connected can disconnect by calling remove. I need to get the observer out of my map by removing it, but overtime I try to remove it I get a ConcurrentModificationException. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @MiguelJ. When you have `Map map` the field `map` is a reference to a `Map`, it is not the object itself.  When you say `final Map map` it means you can't change the *reference* but you can change what it references.  Similarly when you say `volatile Map map` it makes either a read *or* a write to the *reference* thread safe, but nothing in the Map is make thread safe.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Above I have some code from my program.. Do you see any reason why I would be getting the concurrent exception? I am using final now.. Your explanation with that helped a lot I appreciate that.

Comment: @MiguelJ. Your stack trace should tell you that your access to a non thread safe collection e.g. a List has been performed across threads.  However, your line `observerListToCheck.remove(o);` will produce this error even if you have only one thread. this is because you are Iterating while modifying it and it cannot tell that you used the same thread in both cases.  I suggest using a thread safe list AND using Iterator.remove() to remove the entry rather than remove(o).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your help. I ended up simplifying remove() method by a lot, and taking into consideration that I can't remove things while iterating.

Comment: @MiguelJ. You can if you use an Iterator like I suggested.

Comment: @jameslarge agreed, thread safety is not like pixie dust you sprinkle around and magic happens.

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you have only one instance of the object, and your threads can access to it by doeing `Object object = AClass.getInstance();`:

```
public class AClass
{
    private static Object instance;

    public static synchronized Object getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Object();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

`AClass` can also define other methods by which modify the state of the object.

Comment: No. A singleton is't an answer here. Once the reference to the map escapes (`return instance`) that's it.

Comment: Almost what I need, but I am hoping to have access to the same object among multiple threads. Thank you though.